# MVC4: Sending checkbox values as HtmlAttributes when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got an a list of checkboxes on my MVC4 webpage that are generated like this:

```
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">
    <br />
    <h3>@Html.Label("Type de service")</h3>

    @foreach (var serviceType in Model.ServiceTypeList)
    {
        <label>@Html.CheckBox(serviceType.ServiceTypeId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) @serviceType.Description</label><br />
    }

    <br />
    <h3>@Html.Label("Type d'application")</h3>
    @foreach (var appType in Model.ApplicationTypeList)
    {
        <label>@Html.CheckBox(appType.ApplicationId.ToString()) @appType.ApplicationName</label><br />
    }
    <br />
</div>
```

What I want to do now is to send a dictionary for each one of the two lists of checkboxes back to the server when a button is clicked, containing a key/value pair with the ID of the checkbox and a boolean as it's value:

```
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 5px;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, bool>
        {}))
    {
        <input id="btnFilter" type="submit" value="Filter" />
    }
</div>
```

What is the best way to obtain dynamically the values of both of the lists and send them to the server ?

Comment: Are you wanting to post this as an ajax call? It's not clear why you are generating your view like this (and as a result you cant bind back to your model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, it will create 2 array(one for each list) stuctured as 
[id-boolean,id-boolean,id-boolean,id-boolean,]:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            var listOneArray = [];
            var listTwoArray = [];

            $("#listOne input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                var a1 = $(this).attr("id");
                var b1 = $(this).prop("checked");
                listOneArray.push(a1 + "-" + b1.toString());
            });

            $("#listtwo input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                var a2 = $(this).attr("id");
                var b2 = $(this).prop("checked");
                listTwoArray.push(a2 + "-" + b2.toString());
            });

            $.post("Yourcontroller/YourAction", { list1: listOneArray, list2: listTwoArray }, function (data) {
                //do whatever with the response

            });

        });
    });
</script>
```